# Django No Profile Authentication

Tags: python, django, one-time-password

I want to make a django site which has no profile authentication or signing in.  Anonymous users will be able to make a form that will be potentially open to anyone else on the site.

I'd like to do two things:

1. Somehow limit access to this form to certain people, without on site profiles.  Maybe passwords/encryption keys distributed by email?  Or secret one-time links using random URL's to make finding them/crawling them difficult, only accessible to those who know about them?
2. A way that the user who created the form can delete the form.  Again, perhaps email a secret password upon creation to whoever created the form, which can let them delete the form?

Are there any Django plug-ins I should look into, or does anyone have tips about how I should go about this?  I'm interested in the [shareasecret](https://onetimesecret.com/) site, and aspects of security in one time links without profile authentication, however, I'm not sure of best practices and ways to go about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice nor a plugin for this use case. It is a common-or-garden, simple use case which should not demand that much of code and logic that you look for some plugin or best practice. Just draw the picture you imagine, sit and write your code. if you have any exact problems in your code, then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the specific site you're trying to recreate has an [api](https://onetimesecret.com/docs/api/secrets), it would appear that the details aren't matched against the user, but the post itself. so simply make a model that has the two things that it requires

> Query Params
>
> - SECRET_KEY: the unique key for this secret.
> - passphrase (if required): the passphrase is required only if the secret was create with one.

So either I'd suggest use the same method yourself, or just use their api.